# Allah will place his one foot on Hell, will his second stay on footstool (kursiy)?

Tags: hadith, allah, hadith-interpretation

Narrated Anas: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The people will be thrown into the (Hell) Fire and it will say: 'Are there any more (to come)?' (50.30) till Allah puts His Foot over it and it will say, 'Qati! Qati! (Enough Enough!)'"

Sahih al-Bukhari 4848
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4848

---

The Kursi is the place of the feet of Allah, and the size of Throne cannot be known.”
This was narrated by Ibn Khuzaymah in at-Tawhid, 1/248, no. 154 and Hakim in Mustadrak. He classed it as authentic according to the conditions of Bukhari and Muslim and Dhahabi has agreed with him.

Question: second hadith mentions a pair of foot, first mentions only one foot.. does the second foot stay on Kursiy?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You are suggesting that Allah has two feet is that backuped anywhere? Further you assume that Allah can have his foot only in one place which is a restriction that appiles to humans. Note that the scholars of the salaf accept the hadith as stated the Khalaf left many interpretations.

Comment: subahaanallah!.....
"Exalted is Allah above whatever they associate with Him". [59:23]

Answer (score 1):

Ahlus-Sunnah accepts what was authentically narrated, but does not interpret or attempt to look behind the curtain since it creates doubts, discussions and divison. Allah is independent of what He has created and He is not like His creation. So, if Allah describes Himself with **His** Hands or Foot, we just accept it, but do not say that "the Hands or Foot are like ours" or that it would be a metaphor for "might or power" since various Ahadith as well as the Qur'an dispute these kind of approaches.

In Muslim (2277) it is narrated:

> Jabir b. Samura reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:
> "*I recognise the stone in Mecca which used to pay me salutations before my advent as a Prophet and I recognise that even now.*"

There are revelations in the Qur'an and Sunnah which are not conceivable or understandable with our reasoning, but we have to accept it and can not question such specific matters with "how" or "why".

Comment: Alhamdhullilah.